Interfacing pins while in conda environment
I'm using a raspberry pi 5 to interface with a camera whose python library only goes to 3.10, so I made a conda env with 3.10 to work with that library. I'm trying to access the pins at the same time, but whenever I call from gpiozero, "led=LED(4)" I get on "pin = self.pins[info]" a "keyError: PinInfo: ...." which then leads to a "RuntimeError: Cannot determine SOC peripheral base address." When trying other pin libraries I've gotten the SOC error as well. When I run the same script outside of the environment on 3.11, it works and my led lights up. Do I have to dictate in the environment to access the real pins or something?

You are obviously using an old outdated gpiozero but your question is lacking any detail.

@Milliways I'm using gpiozero version 2.0 for both the conda env and just on the pi.

If you are then it is misconfigured. Current version should use lgpio as pin driver which DOES NOT use "SOC peripheral base".
